# Weblogic, log4j and log4jdbc, log in file but not in console

Tags: log4j, log4jdbc

In Weblogic, using log4jdbc, I need to log queries (using org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger) only in a specific file but not in console.

I tried to start Weblogic with this parameter

`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:%LOG4JDBC_HOME%\log4j.xml`

This is the content of log4.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"&gt;
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="File" value="./logs/aladin.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %-30.30c %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <category name="org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </category>
    <category name="org.jdbcdslog.ResultSetLogger">
        <priority value="FATAL" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </category>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>

```
&lt;/log4j:configuration&gt;
```

The problem is that in console I see either org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger and org.jdbcdslog.ResultSetLogger logged at INFO level, in aladin.log (the only file I'd like to log in) I don't see any log of org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger and org.jdbcdslog.ResultSetLogger classes.

Is there a way to log these two classes only in aladin.log and not in console?

Comment: There is an option in under server tab, under  logging , there will be an option to turn on System.out and system.error logs . Please see if this helps

Comment: My problem is that no write sql query into the file defined in log4j.xml. On System.out and error logs either org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger and org.jdbcdslog.ResultSetLogger.<br/>Thanks